# Duda sobre temas pagos de Wordpress y cómo integrarlos si los compra un cliente

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

He completado tres cursos de full stack web development, front end y back-end en Udemy y ahora estoy haciendo otro curso sobre cómo crear tiendas virtuales con el plugin Woocommerce para Wordpress. Me surge ahora la gran duda de cómo hacer para integrar temas pagos/premium a la tienda virtual una vez que me lance como desarrollador web freelance.
Me refiero a que si por ejemplo un cliente quiere usar un tema premium para su tienda virtual, cómo  debería proceder para que yo pueda usarlo en la etapa de desarrollo, para configurarlo, retocar estilos css, etc, si es el cliente el que va a comprar dicho tema pago.
¿Se pueden comprar temas premium para otras personas?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar al respecto.

Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Pensé que estaba claro, sorry. Mi duda es si cuando se compra un tema pago de Wordpress te dan un link para integrarlo a WordPress. Por ejemplo, que yo como desarrollador web tenga un cliente que quiere usar un tema pago en el sitio que estoy creando, que lo adquiera por su lado. ¿Cómo accede el desarrollador web a dicho tema pago?

Comment: Cuando tu compras un theme de wordpress, en realidad, compras el código fuente de dicho theme (mayormente escrito en PHP), con una estructura de carpetas/archivos de código y una base de datos. Luego es tu trabajo subir dicha estructura de carpetas y archivos con código fuente (copiar y pegar) al servidor donde vayas a alojar la web. Al tener acceso al código fuente, pues ya es ir retocándolo a tu gusto desde la base/plantilla que ellos te proporcionan.

Comment: Y sí, un theme puede comprarlo quien quiera (cliente o programador). El caso es tener acceso al servidor o hosting donde se vaya a alojar la web final y subir ahí la página.

Comment: Ese archivo con el código fuente es un .zip, verdad? Es lo que pude ver buscando un poco mas en internet. Sería cuestión de que mi cliente me pasara ese .zip y yo descomprimirlo y subirlo al sitio web de wordpress que estoy creando, no?

Answer (score 0):

En wordpress hay una serie de licencias GPL, aquí tienes más información https://kinsta.com/es/aprender/wordpress-gpl/ recuerda que el objetivo es aportar a la comunidad de wordpress y no tener software gratuito. Por tanto si tu objetivo es aprender para que luego tus clientes compren ese software considero legitimo que utilices una licencia GPL ya que vas a recompensar al desarrollador cuando tu cliente compre el producto premium.